# How to access ILOG CPLEX studio decision variable

Tags: cplex

I have a linear integer problem modeled in IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio, that returns correct solutions, i.e. objective values. But can not access to decision variable (No value). How to access ILOG CPLEX studio decision variable?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.
I flagged this question for closing.

Answer (score 0):

in OPL you may use writeln in the postprocess.
Let me give you an example:

```
dvar int+ Gas;
dvar int+ Chloride;


maximize
  40 * Gas + 50 * Chloride;
subject to {
  ctMaxTotal:     
   Gas + Chloride <= 50;
  ctMaxTotal2:    
    3 * Gas + 4 * Chloride <= 180;
  ctMaxChloride:  
   Chloride <= 40;
}

 execute
 {
   writeln("Chloride=",Chloride);
   writeln("Gas=",Gas);
  }
```